# Can a sound be played as soon as a page is loaded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to play a sound as soon as a page dispalyed. I am currently playing sounds using a IBAction doSound after a button is pressed. This works as intended. But, I am also wanting to play music or a short verbal instruction as soon as the page is displayed. I would like to use the same IBAction since it is already set up, but was not sure if this is a correct use of the function.

Comment: You don't really mean that you want to play sounds in XCode do you? :)

Answer (score 1):

Override the method `viewDidLoad` and put your audio playing code there. That will make it so every time a page is displayed a sound will start up.

If you only want a sound to be played once go to your appDelegate.m and override the method that says `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and place your audio code there.

EDIT:

As Kristopher Johnson has pointed out: it may be better to override `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillLoad`. But, `viewDidLoad` has worked perfectly for me in the past.

Comment: ah ok. yes, this particular sound file only needs to be played once after the page is loaded. will use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. if i want some theme music, i will will you use method viewDidLoad. thanks.

Comment: Might `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` be a better method to override than `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @Kristopher Johnson: Nice catch. In fact, I'm probably going to start changing the way I've written some of my iPhone apps.